# Create Template Page in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am unable to create template page in sharepoint 2013.

Is there a way to do so ?

Thank You !

Comment: is it a site template that you are trying to create?

Comment: No, Page template .. 
I create a page with exact template .. Everyone else will create his own version using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a page layout:
Browse to your publishing site.
In the upper-right corner of the page, choose the gear icon, and then choose Design Manager.

In Design Manager, in the left navigation pane, choose Edit Page Layouts.
Choose Create a page layout.

In the Create a Page Layout dialog box, enter a name for your page layout.
Select a master page.

The master page that you choose here will be shown in the preview for this page layout. This master page also determines what content placeholders get added to the page layout.

Note
After you choose this master page, you cannot preview the page layout with a different master page, even after you apply a different master page to the live site.

Select a content type. The content type for this page layout determines what page fields will be available for this page layout in the Snippet Gallery.
Choose OK.

At this point, SharePoint creates an HTML file and an .aspx file with the same name. In Design Manager, your HTML file now appears with a Status column that shows one of two possible statuses:

1. Warnings and Errors
2. Conversion successful

Click the link in the Status column to preview the file and to view any errors or warnings about the master page.

The preview page is a live server-side preview of your page layout. The top of the preview displays any warnings or errors that you may have to resolve by editing the HTML file in an HTML editor. Errors must be fixed before the preview will display the page layout correctly.

The preview page also contains a Snippets link in the upper-right corner. This link opens the Snippet Gallery, where you can begin replacing mockup controls in your design with dynamic SharePoint controls.

To fix any errors, edit the HTML file that resides directly on the server by using an HTML editor to open and edit the HTML file in the mapped drive. Each time you save the HTML file, any changes are synced to the associated .aspx file.
The preview of the page layout shows the page fields that were added automatically to the page layout. These page fields are site columns that are unique to the current content type. Now you are ready to style the page layout according to your original HTML mockups.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368.aspx)

Comment: well that's how you do it ..sorry.. can you accept my answer?